# PLDI shows twice in people’s profile

Tags: bug, beta

On the proposal page, certain user’s top communities, for example rydwolf, show PLDI twice. I know we’re awesome, but not that awesome (or are we?) What’s happening and can this be fixed?

UPDATE:I believe that one goes to the old domain languagedesign which redirects to langdev. The second actually goes to langdev without the redirect. Could one of the CMs fix this?

Comment: Could have to do with the fact that the domain recently changed?

Comment: Possible…staff input welcome…@Bbrk24

Comment: Yes, it is because one link goes to languagedesign and the other langdev @Bbrk24